# Запуск GUI приложения от рута в OpenSuse

Tags: linux, администрирование, консоль, opensuse

Под `Ubuntu` приложение перезапускает себя от рута при помощи команд:

```
gksu "path to app"
```

или

```
beesu "path to app"
```

пользователь вводит пароль рута и приложение запускается от рута.

Пытаюсь реализовать такое же поведение под `OpenSuze`. `gksu` и `beesu` запрещены. От рута приложение перезапускается командой:

```
xdg-su -u root -c "path to app"
```

Но после ввода пароля диалог закрывается и программа не запускается. 
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а в логи смотрели?

Comment: А зачем вводить пароль рута? Это тупо. Давным-давно, в далекой-далекой галактике был придуман `sudo` именно для того, чтобы не знать пароль от рута, но иметь полный (или не совсем) доступ.

Comment: Программа должна работать на пользовательской машине. Как при помощи sudo сделать тоже самое, что делает xdg-su мне не понятно.

Comment: Проблема частично решена. На старте программа выполняла
     if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
     {
            if (fork())
                return 0;
      setsid();
        }
Если это закомментировать, то последующий xdg-su успешно запускает программу под рутом. К сожалению, не знаю с какой целью написан код выше.